# the comment appears only after the last post

Tags: php, mysqli

I made a comment page for the users to post and other people can comment on they posts it runs very good but there's one problem I think it's easy but I can't get it, when the user comment on post 'one' it appear normally but when there is 3 or 5 etc. the comment one doesn't appear like it's not there so in the end I can make it very clear that the last post comments appears but if there is any other comments on the top of it. it doesn't appear

this is my code

```
<?php
    >               
    >       $getBlogs = "select * from blogs where active = 1";
    >       $blogResults = $db -> query ($getBlogs) or die ($db->error);        if
    > ($blogResults) {
    >                       while ($blog = $blogResults -> fetch_object()) {
    >               
    >               ?>
    >               
    >                 
    >                 
    >                 <table width="600" border="0" cellpadding="0"
    > cellspacing="0">
    >                   <tr class="bons">
    >                     <td width="62" align="right" valign="middle"
    > class="blogIBg"><img src="images/blog.png" width="37" height="30"
    > /></td>
    >                     <td width="243" height="28" class="blogSBg"><?php
    > echo $blog->Btitle; ?></td>
    >                     <td width="78" height="28" class="blogSBg"><span
    > class="by11">Posted by :</span></td>
    >                     <td width="117" height="28" class="blogSBg"><span
    > class="blogby12Bg"><span class="red"><b><?php echo $blog->ByName;
    > ?></b></span></span></td>
    >                     <td width="100" class="blogSBg"><span
    > class="by11"><?php echo $blog->dateAdded ?></span></td>
    >                   </tr>
    >                   <tr>
    >                     <td>&nbsp;</td>
    >                     <td colspan="4" class="blogBBg"><?php echo
    > $blog->Bdescription; ?></td>
    >                   </tr>
    >                   <tr>
    >                     <td>&nbsp;</td>
    >                     <td colspan="4" align="right" bgcolor="#D5F1FF"
    > class="blogby11Bg"><a class='example7'
    > href="includes/postComments.php?id=<?php $gotIT=$blog->id; echo
    > $gotIT; ?>">Comment</a></td>
    >                   </tr>
    >                 </table>
    >                 <br />               
    >                    <?php
    >               
    >               }           }
    >                       $comments = "select * from blogscomments where blogestID =
    > $gotIT";          $resultComments = $db -> query ($comments) or die
    > ($db->error);
    >                       if ($resultComments) {
    >               
    >               
    >                   while ($dig = $resultComments -> fetch_object()) {
    >                        ?>
    >                       
    >                           <table width="500" border="0">
    >                               <tr>
    >                                 <td width="32">&nbsp;</td>
    >                                 <td width="197"><?php echo
    > $dig->comments; ?></td>
    >                               </tr>
    >                             </table>
    >                             
    >                             
    >                       <?php
    >                       
    >                       }
    >               
    >               } ?>
    > 
    > </div>
```

I have type the whole code to give a full idea,

and the code is responsible for the comments to appear is this.

```
$comments = "select * from blogscomments where blogestID =
 $gotIT";             $resultComments = $db -> query ($comments) or die
 ($db->error);
                      if ($resultComments) {


                   while ($dig = $resultComments -> fetch_object()) {
                        ?>

                          <table width="500" border="0">
                              <tr>
                                <td width="32">&nbsp;</td>
                               <td width="197"><?php echo
 $dig->comments; ?></td>
                               </tr>
                             </table>


                       <?php

                       }

               } ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for everybody I just got it and it was very easy like I side I made the separate php file called handlingComments.php and I put this code as will

```
<?php

$comments = "select * from blogscomments where blogestID = $gotIT";
            $resultComments = $db -> query ($comments) or die ($db->error);

            if ($resultComments) {


                    while ($dig = $resultComments -> fetch_object()) {

     ?>               
                    <table width="500" border="0">
                              <tr>
                                <td width="32">&nbsp;</td>
                                <td width="197"><?php echo $dig->comments; ?></td>
                              </tr>
                            </table>


                        <?php

                        }

                }
?>
```

and then I included in the main blog page and it's running very good now.

Thanks again everybody,